# JSOUP execution stopping unexpectedly

Tags: java, jsoup

I have lines of code that trying to make a connection with JSoup:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
     new Test();
}
    
    
public Test(){
     new Worker().execute();  
}


class Worker extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer>{
        protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception{
    
           while(true){

           ...

                Connection.Response con = Jsoup.connect(URL)
                          .method(org.jsoup.Connection.Method.GET)
                          .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                          .timeout(100000)
                          .execute();

           ...

           }
    ...
    }
}
```

But when it arrives on the "execute()" part, my whole program stops.
What should be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: works for me for url `http://www.google.com`, can you share more details like which url you are trying yo hit.

Comment: it's an url used by my organization.
 But on another program, it has worked using the same url.

Comment: You will need to at least post the exception stacktrace for anyone to be able to help you.